# I need selenium to check a box, but I can't check it

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need selenium to check a box, but I can't check it. When I input the Xpath, it just clicks the hyperlink in the text (as seen in image 2). Some background, I code my script in Selenium Python, I am new to coding.

I don't know what the element of the checkbox itself is called, but I figured the checkbox is the purple line that says "::before". I feel like I've tried every possible way to code this.

If more information is needed, just ask.

[When you inspect it in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erBll.png)

[The box I'm trying to tick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85FnL.png)

[The HTML of the parent element (I think)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FXeN.png)

Comment: Add html code in a snippet or as a code. It is hard to guess.

Comment: Also, add at least an xpath you are trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//input[@id='denmark.agreeToTerms']").click()
```

Comment: it clicks on the text, not the checkbox, I have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show what locator are you using.
Anyway, I guess the correct locator of the checkbox is the following XPath

```
//input[@id='denmark.agreeToTerms']
```

if you prefer `css_selector` -

```
input#denmark.agreeToTerms
```

Comment: I have tried different locators, if I find it by XPath, or any of the other locators it clicks the text it is grouped with instead of the checkbox.

Comment: Probably you provided a wrong HTML. It would be better if you provide the link to the web page itselt

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@for='denmark.agreeToTerms']").click()
```

For checkboxes click the label tag.

Comment: I know how to click it by Xpath, as explained it clicks the text it is grouped with, instead of the checkbox. I can't get the Xpath of the checkbox itself, only the text and checkbox together, when you try to click them together, it clicks in the middle of them both, and that is a hyperlink, not the checkbox.
if you look at the first picture the purple text highlighted is the actual checkbox, I can't find a locator that locates the actual purple text, because it has no Xpath, class or id.